# Visual Studio is stopping in the disassembly when no breakpoints are set up

Tags: visual-studio-2010, interop, visual-studio-debugging

I have a project using interop code (managed c++ calling unmanaged c++) that I am trying to debug into.  Currently I have no break points set up, and yet Visual Studio is stopping in the Disassembly for a third party dll, as if I had stepped into it manually.  The debugger then seems to get stuck on one line.

The program debugs and runs fine until I "Enable unmanaged code debugging" in the project for the executable.

Has anyone experienced anything like this, and knows why it happens or how to solve it?

My build type is Debug | x86, environment Visual Studio 2010/Windows 7 64bit.

Many thanks!

Some additional info:

Call Stack:

```
apidsp_windows.dll!157946a9()
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for apidsp_windows.dll]
apidsp_windows.dll!1577b7bb() 
ntdll.dll!779c9950()
```

Output window:

```
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x27a0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'MyProgram.exe': Loaded 'C:\...\apidsp_windows.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
```

Comment: Several good reasons.  But this is not Youtube, you have to *describe* what you see.  At least the last few lines in the Output window and the content of the Call Stack debugger window.

Comment: I would have if I thought it would be useful.  It is just what one would expect if you had stepped into a dll which had no debug symbols.